# How to show that the entire function $f(z) = z^2 + \cos{z}$ has range all of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been thinking about the following exercise from an old complex analysis qualifier exam for some days but I still don't know how to solve it. The problem is as follows:

> Show that the entire function $f(z) := z^2 + \cos{z}$  has range all of $\mathbb{C}$.

At first I thought that maybe I could use [Picard's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem#The_theorems) to get a contradiction. I thought that maybe by considering the function $e^{f(z)}$ I could get the contradiction by asssuming that $f(z)$ misses one point so that the exponential would miss two points and that would contradict Picard's Little Theorem, but since the exponential is periodic this argument doesn't work.

> So my question is how can this be proved?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a similar proof as in the question [What is the image near the essential singularity of z sin(1/z)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/what-is-the-image-near-the-essential-singularity-of-z-sin1-z) would work here too.

The function $g(z) = z + \cos (\sqrt{z})$ is of order $\frac{1}{2}$ (someone should verify that...) and so does not miss any points by [Picard's first theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=DYCOCBCBwoIC&pg=PA268#v=onepage&q&f=false) (the link is a google books link).

Comment: I will look at both links. Thank you.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: You are welcome!

Comment: Does $\cos\sqrt{z}$ an entire function?

Comment: @Ylath: Yes, I believe so.