# A confusion about Picard's little theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Picard's little theorem says that an entire function that omits two values is constant. The following confusion is based on a comment saying that "if an entire function omits one value, then exponential of this function will omit two values and thus constant".

The above comment was in the post

[How to show that the entire function $f(z) = z^2 + \cos{z}$ has range all of $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119488/how-to-show-that-the-entire-function-fz-z2-cosz-has-range-all-of-m)

Consider $f(z)=\exp(e^z)$. The function $e^z$ omits the value $0$, so $\exp(e^z)$ omits the values $0,1$. This implies $f$ is constant.

It is obvious that $f$ is not constant. So where did I go wrong?

Edit: $\exp$ takes value $1$ at $2k\pi i$.

Comment: Ummm  $\exp (2\pi i)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You went wrong when you wrote that $f$ omits $1$. Take $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $e^z=2\pi i$, and then$$f(z)=\exp(2\pi i)=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies that the original comment does not hold.