# number of zeros of function $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)-1$$

How many zeros does the above function have in $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: That product is famous.  Do you know an elementary function representation of it?  Where is the problem from?

Comment: @JonasMeyer. someone ask me the number of zeros of $f(z)=\sin(z)-z$ in $\Bbb{C}$. and I use the fact $\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}=z\prod\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ to get this problem.

Comment: Rush: Why not tell us that before?  Anyway, thank you very much for clarifying.

Comment: @JonasMeyer. thanks for you advice. I will do it next time

Comment: Since it does not have a pole, I guess that argument principle will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment, this is essentially the problem of determining the number of solutions to $\sin(z)=z$.  There are infinitely many. It turns out more generally, as I learned from [Aryabhata's answer at this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3157), with reference to [an example in Markuševič's book at this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=DYCOCBCBwoIC&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q&f=false), that for every complex number $A$, the equation $\sin(z)=Az$ has infinitely many solutions in the complex plane.